# Replacing Inf Values with 0 Given a List of Columns in R

Tags: r, replace, apply, infinite

I'm terrible at apply functions and every answer I looked up on here somehow is hard for me to apply to this problem, I've tried as hard as I've can to not post here.

I have a list of column names called "log_fields"

I want to go through each of these columns in my data frame "df" and replace the infinite values with 0.

This is the code I'm currently trying to use, their must be a syntax error with my function argument because I'm being told the argument values is missing.

```
sapply(df[log_fields], function(x) replace(is.infinite(x),0))
```

I'm incredibly greatful for the help!

Comment: or `lapply (df[log_fields], function(x) {x[is.infinite(x)] <- 0;x})`

Answer (score 2):

`lapply(df[log_fields], function(x) ifelse(is.infinite(x), 0, x))` as [李哲源](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4891738/%e6%9d%8e%e5%93%b2%e6%ba%90) suggested.

`lapply (df[log_fields], function(x) {x[is.infinite(x)] <- 0;x})` as [dww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2761575/dww) suggested.